# multistring search mode in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a html content with all structure(html, head and others tags). I need to get body content, so I do

```
data = data.replace(/.*<body.*?>(.*)<\/body>/mi,"$1");
```

but that regexp seems to be not working, what I am doing wrong?

Comment: what's the content of `data`? Could you provide a fiddle?

Comment: any page, open any page of the internet, content is html source of the page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript doesn't support the `s` (=dot matches newlines) switch, so you'll have to use `[^]` (=any character) instead of `.`

```
"<\n xxx \n>".replace(/<.*>/, "YES")  // < xxx >
"<\n xxx \n>".replace(/<[^]*>/, "YES") // YES
```

Comment: In JS you can use `[^]` to match any char.

Comment: @Qtax: nice, didn't know that.

Comment: @OleksandrKhavdiy: interesting. In which browser is that? As a workaround, try `[\s\S]`, this should work everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

There's no flag to make `.` match new line, so you'll have to add it to matching manually. I suggest using whitespace class `\s`. Also, initial `.*` is not needed.

```
data = data.replace(/<body.*?>((\s|.)*)<\/body>/mi,"$1");
```